# Updating static files on Amazon S3 from Zend application

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

we inherited Zend project, which hosts all static files (css, js, images, ..) on Amazon S3. Original programmer told me, that deployment is automated, but when I update new (for example) css file on server, on S3 is still old version.
Same guy linked me this article: http://www.labnol.org/internet/lower-amazon-s3-bill-improve-website-loading-time/5193/, where is section "Implement Caching for Amazon S3 Files". I added ?v param for my css file, but it didn't help.

I set permissions in Amazon S3 console for user "info" (I'm logged as info@domain.tld) to: Open/Download, View Permissions and Edit permissions for mentioned css file.

Is it possible, that Zend can update static files on Amazon S3, or it's bad info? I tried to search in Zend doc, but unsuccessfully.

Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework does offer a component to connect and work with Amazon S3. check out 
[Zend Framework S3](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html)

It dosen't matter what kind of file (object) it is, it can be updated.
If you can find it post some of the update code and maybe someone can troubleshoot it.

Comment: But I don't know how to automatically update static files on Amazon S3